# Use an image for canvas background

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-studio

Im creating a game on for android, using Android studio.

At the moment I just have a black background. How can i use an image instead?

This is what i use to make it black:

```
canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Are you using a layout xml file?

Answer (score 1):

First load your image as a bitmap:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.your_background_image);
```

You can then create a canvas over the bitmap:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));
```